# Excel: Automatically Insert Checkbox (according to some conditions)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, development

**TL;DR:** I want to automatically generate independent checkbox controls in cells based on their value and nearby values.

---

**Long version:**

I have a spreadsheet in which some cells are truly blank, some cells appear blank but are not (due to conditional formatting - this is determined by the value of the cell above and is already implemented), and some cells display their value (which will always be text). In advance, I will not know which cells will be of any given class among these; the data is going to be entered by the user - all that I can do is set up the sheet so that it functions for them as desired once they do.

I want to know how to make it so that Excel will automatically insert a checkbox control in any cell which *appears* as nonempty (and actually has a value) such that the checkbox corresponds to the same cell as that in which it appears in another sheet (evaluating to `TRUE` there iff the checkbox is checked) and vice-versa.

Summary:

- So, no truly blank cell will get a checkbox and no cell which looks blank (even if it is not) will get a checkbox.
- If cell B3 in Sheet1 has a checkbox, then cell B3 in Sheet2 will evaluate to `TRUE` iff that checkbox is checked; meanwhile, If cell B4 in Sheet1 has a checkbox, then cell B4 in Sheet2 will evaluate to `TRUE` iff that checkbox is checked - independent of the checkbox in B3 of Sheet1 or the value of B3 in Sheet2. In particular, it must be possible for the generated checkboxes to be mutually independently checked/selected and for their selection to produce a `TRUE` result in accessibly predetermined and fixed cells to which their results map bijectively; copying the checkbox, as far as I know, will not work because the resulting copies are neither mutually independent (and independent of the original) nor bijectively mapped to a predetermined and fixed cell which I can access.
- These checkbox controls would be generated automatically and inserted in the proper places once the cells are filled out.
- If the contents/value of a cell are/is deleted or if the cell should come to appear blank (even if it is not), then that cell will lose its checkbox automatically and the corresponding cell in the other sheet will either become blank or will evaluate to `FALSE` (until the checkbox appears again AND is affirmatively checked/selected again).

Comment: Sounds like you'll need some VBA but we couldn't write that for you, it's beyond the scope of this website. 

Using checkbox controls complicates things quite a lot - is there a reason you're using these rather than just a column of cells that work in the same way?

Comment: Mostly because the desire is to make user interface intuitive and effortless. (Unfortunately, that means that I have to put the effort in). I am willing to hear alternatives, though!

I know nothing of how VBAs work. Do you have any resources?